# Selenium find button inside div by XPath

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I need to find "Confirm" and click on.

```
<div class="sidebar-element-confirm">
  <ui-button class="btn btn-xm sidebar-element-confirm" type="button">
  Confirm
  </ui-button>
</div>
```

My solutions are (neither of them works -- no exception, no error):

```
private val element1 = "//div[@class='sidebar-element-confirm']/ui-button[contains(text(),'Confirm')]" 
private val element2 = "//div[@class='sidebar-element-confirm']/ui-button[@type='button']"
driver.findElement(By.xpath(element1)) --does not work
driver.findElement(By.xpath(element2)) --does not work
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my XPath?

---

**Updated #1:**

Chrome (XPath) gives me:

```
//*[@id="right-sidebar"]/div/div[2]/ui-button
```

However, this XPath did not work:

```
val chrome_xpath = "//*[@id='right-sidebar']/div/div[2]/ui-button"   
webDriver.get(URL)
searchId.sendKeys(Id) --put id of order
searchId.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) -- ENTER
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

... the order is loading, then I need to click on "Confirm".

```
assert(webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(chrome_xpath).isInstanceOf[WebElement])  # true
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(chrome_xpath)).click`
```

Button was not touched. Exception:

> StaleElementReferenceExpection:Element is no longer valid. Thrown at a line when I tried to click the button

**Updated #2:**

`private val confirmButton = ".btn.btn-sm.btn-block"
webdriver.get(URL)
login --and Spinning
ExplicitWait until some element is found on the page
findElement -- put there an Order ID and press Enter --and Spinning
ExplicitWait until Order is appeared on the page
findElement(By.cssSelector(confirmButton)).click -- passed only once! --and Spinning
ExplicitWait`

> The rest of mine attempts were failed either by "IE driver has stopped" or "StaleElementException" or "Element is no longer exists"

Would you please tell me if i do smth wrong in designing that test?

Comment: First XPath does not work because `'Affirm' != 'Confirm'`. Second one seem to be OK. Try Explicit/Implicit wait or check whether button located inside frame/iframe. Also you need to share exception log instead of *...does not work...*

Comment: First guess.. None of your commands actually `.click()` on anything so there is nothing **to** work. If that's not the answer, you will need to add more details and not just "does not work"

Comment: confirming what @Andersson said is true, maybe you could provide more context since that small part of html vs the entire page may have different result , try to look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kksqbxkr/)

Comment: Hi @Andersson. Thanks for your comment, i will be trying to figure it out what is wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

**Use this following XPath:**

```
1. //*[normalize-space()='Confirm'] 
2. //div[normalize-space()='Confirm'] 
3. //div//ui-button[normalize-space()='Confirm']
```

`normalize-space()`: Remove the spaces before and after a string that placed in between HTML tags.

Comment: unfortunately none of the xpaths helped me. Thank you for your help